# How do i obtain unpaid / paid but not send orders from using ebay REST API via chilkat library?

Tags: vb6, rest, orders, ebay-api, chilkat

can anyone help me provide a hint on how to obtain orders from the ebay Sell/Order API ( not the xml, the REST-API)

the most obvious question is: which node is the right one? Buy/orders API (https://developer.ebay.com/api-docs/buy/order/static/overview.html) in my opinion isn't the right because:

- i (the user of the endproduct) am the owner of the ebay account
- i dont want to buy something i want to see what anyone else have bought from me (the items i sell on ebay)
- i only want to see the orders which are unpaid (buyer hasn't payed yet) or which are not send to the buyer but the buyer has already payed.

from my understanding this API (REST-API buy/order) is only for someone who wants to build an App in which you can buy something from ebay directly. Correct me if i am wrong.

If my understandings are right then which REST-API from ebay would be the best / most feasable to use?

i quite literally lose track on which Ebay API Node does what - the eBay-"Support"-Team "helped" by sending me an "please rate us"-Mail instead of answering the questions i asked- not quite useful, so i kindly ask the gods of stackoverflow or maybe Mr. Chilkat Software himself if i am lucky?

Next Step, if someone could help would be how to use them with the Chilkat Software ActiveX Library? I would love to use this Library because he's providing a ton of good examples which are working flawlessly and without any doubts or misleadings.

Also the library is working in VB6/VBA which is the target to implement it.

```
https://www.example-code.com/vb6/ebay.asp
```

I know, its a pain in the butt but there is no real alternative for the task i need to resolve and there's only a little piece of the puzzle left missing to paint the great picture complete.

I would love to hear from you and get help in my task/journey.

Thanks in advance